# How do you implement a snap-to-grid in QGraphicsScene? Mine didn't work

Tags: qt, pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, snap-to-grid

I don't have any code to show because this was over a year ago.  I used a timer I think.  It did not work very professionally.  How would you do it so that it is a smooth operator?

I am already able to draw the grid efficiently (ie. in view only).  I just need the snapping algorithm.

Comment: Many different things can be snapped to a grid, in many different ways. What exact behavior are you trying to implement? Please describe the interaction from a user's perspective, in detail (edit the question then flag this comment as obsolete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my `mouseReleaseEvent` for `QGraphicsItem`'s derivative class. Grid has a step equal to 5:

```
void RadBox::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    double xx=x();
    double yy=y();
    if((int)xx / 5 != xx/5.) xx=5.0*round(xx/5.);
    if((int)yy / 5 != yy/5.) yy=5.0*round(yy/5.);
    setPos(xx,yy);
    QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    emit moveBox(id,scenePos().x(),scenePos().y()); // you don't need this line, it's specific to my program
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-implement `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()` to react upon the `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange` change. Don't forget to set the `QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag.